# getting server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter mvc . i want rewrite my route 
at the moment its like that

```
http://localhost/abc/index.php/blog
```

I want it like

```
 http://localhost/abc/blog
```

for this i change in my htaccess file using this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /abc/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

when i change i am getting server 500 error

Answer (score 0):

.htacess example is available on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html. Remove index.php in application/config/config.php - change to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```